# Convert a double rating into images with IValueConverter

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, rating, winrt-xaml, ivalueconverter

I get a rating of meals from a webservice as a double value.

In my Xaml I want to convert this value into star images. The range is from 0 - 5 and I want be able to convert every 0.5 steps.

If I get a rating of 3.75, I want to have three "full stars" and a half star. For an example take a look at this website: [click me](http://www.doenermap.de/details/zel_d%C3%B6ner.html)

How can I achieve this via Xaml?

**SOLUTION:**

Found a working control here: http://metrorate.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working control here: http://metrorate.codeplex.com/